# Нужна узнать Default display , HTML anchor Элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть HTML  `<a style="display:none">` элемент которому я назначаю стиль `display:none`, после некоторого времени нужно вернуть default display элемента, но он мне неизвестен.

Как узнать default display `<a>` элемента, и *других* HTML элементов  ?

Если есть ссылки по этому вопросу буду рад посмотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Есть дефолтные свойства CSS, которые присваиваются тупо любому элементу. Вот они:
   https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html
2. Затем на это все дело накладывается вот эти свойства:
   https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Если взять ссылку `<a></a>`, то сначала смотрим в первую таблицу и там говорится, что *display:inline* по дефолту присваивается всем элемента.

Потом смотрим в таблицу вторую и видим, что там нет `<a></a>`. Значит, `<a></a>` - это инлайновый элемент по дефолту

Answer (score 1):

Для сброса инлайн стиля достаточно присвоить ему пустую строку:

```
el.style.display = '';
```

А так же можно просто вызвать `$(el).show()`